# Angular instant search with filter is not working on JSON api calls

Tags: angularjs, json, api, search, angular-ngmodel

I was trying to collect JSON data from an API endpoint using AngularJS and that worked just fine. I was able to make list using the datas. Also tried to include an input to search. But the instant search with filter is not working. I double checked the syntax but seems like it is just fine. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

> ```
>             <label>Search: <input type="text" ng-model="search"> </label>
>                     <div class="list-group">
>                                 <div ng-app="listBuilderFromJsonData" ng-controller="listDatasBootstrap">
>                                     <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="data in datas | filter:search">
>                                         {{data.title}}
>                                 </a>
>                               </div>
>                             </div>                    
>                     <script>
>                      var app= angular.module('listBuilderFromJsonData', []);
>                        app.controller('listDatasBootstrap', function($scope, $http){
>                         $http.get("https://api.end.point.url").then(function(response){
>                             $scope.datas = response.data.items;             
>                         });
>                         });
>                 </script>
> ```

Comment: where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your ng-app at the root level. Here your textbox for search is outside ng-app